# TimeCop not adjusting time in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, timecop

Using Rails, Rspec, FactoryBot, Capybara, Whenever, TimeCop.

I'm trying to trigger a modal method at '00:01, every 1.day' (12:01am daily) during an Rspec/Capybara test, in order to test the code that is triggered in the Cron. I'm trying TimeCop to travel back to 00:00:30 of the current day in order to trigger the cron scheduled for 00:01.

Essentially I need to figure out how to fire cron on cue in test environment, so I can test the code that the various cron jobs initiates. Some cron are scheduled for once a day, some once a month etc., so I was hoping to set up TimeCop to travel to the right time, slightly before the Cron is scheduled, so I can start the cron job and test the code in Rspec.

Rspec (set TimeCop time to 12:01 am of current day):

```
let (:time_travel) do
  new_time = Time.local(Time.new.year, Time.new.month, Time.new.day, 0, 0, 30)
  Timecop.travel(new_time)
end
```

Problem is, the cron is not firing the cron that is scheduled for 00:01, and I assume it is because the modal method is being interpreted at runtime, before TimeCop travels through time, because if I run the cron every 1.minute, and put this in the modal method:

Modal method code:

```
def self.transfer_to_host
    puts "1 ========#{Time.now} --- Time.now (local)"
    puts "2 ========#{Time.now.utc} --- Time.now (utc)"
```

The cron_log.log shows my machine's local time (not TimeCop time):

```
1 ========2023-10-26 10:00:06 -0400 --- Time.now (local)
2 ========2023-10-26 14:00:06 UTC --- Time.now (utc)
```

But while if I binding.pry in the Rspec, it shows theTimeCop time:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HPETRANSFER>)> Time.now
=> 2023-10-26 00:00:47 -0400
```

How do I get TimeCop to reach schedule.rb and HostPublicEvent.transfer_to_host, so that they fire at 00:01?

Schedule.rb (whenever)

```
every 1.day, :at => '00:01' do
  runner "HostPublicEvent.transfer_to_host", :environment => 'test'
end
```

Rspec:

```
describe "HPE TRANSFER ", type: :system do

  let (:time_travel) do
   new_time = Time.local(Time.new.year, Time.new.month, Time.new.day, 0, 0, 30)
   Timecop.travel(new_time)
  end

  ....
  scenario "MONEY TRANSFER TO HOST AFTER A WEEK", :js => true do

    ...
    ...
    time_travel

    visit root_path

    sleep 1
    click_on "I agree"
    binding.pry
```

I'm not sure how to get TimeCop to adjust time in model method.

Comment: My guess is that your spec isn't running in the same process. Doesn't whenever provide some kind of utility for stubbing or a test mode that you can use?

Comment: I appreciate that, ty.  ... going by the cron_log.log (if I set it to run every 1.minute), the Cron is initiated immediately, long before even the FactoryBot instances are made. Then the FactoryBot instances are made, and then the TimeCop arrives on the scene, uselessly. I'm an amateur, but I'm thinking this has to be a standard scenerio? How does one test the code that is initiated by a cron job?

Comment: ... there is a whenever-test gem, which "This gem implements a class that has the same DSL interface as Whenever gem. It basically runs the schedule.rb file against Whenever::Test::DSLInterpreter and stores all statements and parameters found so you can easily query them in your tests."  ... doesn't allow me to trigger cron jobs in the future I don't think.

Comment: I'm unclear on what it is you're trying to test here. Are you testing that cron fires when you expect it to? (If so, why?) Or, are you testing your business logic? (If not, why?)

Comment: Ty - I'm trying to figure out how to fire cron on cue in test environment, so I can test the code that the various cron jobs initiates. Some cron fires once a day, some once a month etc., so I was hoping to set up TimeCop to travel to the right time, slightly before the Cron is scheduled.

Comment: I don't think that will work. Timecop just changes how the Ruby time and date classes work. It doesn't change the system clock that cron relies on.

Comment: Cron (like controllers and cables and jobs) is the mechanism through which your code is invoked. You don't need to test it (or those other things). What you want to test is your code. So, extract the code that needs to be tested into an object that can be tested outside the context of cron, then just call that code from cron. You can assume the developers of cron and Rails tested what they built.

Comment: I appreciate that thank you both, and I have done just that